# atan() of a number in JavaScript when transforming x,y coordinates to longitude and latitude

Tags: javascript

I am using the Web Mercator to transform longitudes and latitudes to x and y coordinates. However, when I want to inverse this problem the built-in `atan()` (or `Math.atan()`) function of JavaScript (and p5.js) gives me trouble. The Web Mercator and the calculated inverse are given below.

[formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa52z.gif)

Then, for an example y position in my grid, I have code similar to:

```
//Sample code for transforming y coordinate to latitude using Web Mercator
//map size: 128x128 -> c_map = 128, zoom level: 1
var ypos = 100;
var c_map = 128;
var temp = PI*(1- ypos/(pow(2, 1)*c_map);
temp = atan(exp(temp) * 180/PI);
lat = 2*(180 / PI)*(temp - PI / 4);
```

However, this gives me false values for the y coordinate since JavaScript computes the tangent and arctangent in radians. 
I have tried several configurations of first transforming the exponent to radians (is the exponent in degrees?) and then transforming the result back to degrees, but to no avail. The y coordinates are given relative to the point [0,0].

What kind of radian/degree transformation do I need to apply where in order to get correct values of my y coordinate?

Comment: Convert to radians: `atan(exp(temp) * PI / 180)`

Comment: This does not work sadly. I can make a working example, but my y-coordinate is never mapped to be 0 at the equator and +-90 at the poles. All attempts with conversion to radians or degrees has failed me up until now.